# Python Speech Recognition not starting without saying anything

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio, pyttsx3

I am creating a Python Personal Assistant using Python's Speech Recognition,pyaudio and Python Text to speech modules, so what I want is that after starting the program I want it to say something and have coded it the same, but when I run the program, It starts listening first and until and unless I provide it with any random word it does not move forward. Here is the code for the main function.

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import random
import functions.Response as speech
import functions.custom_input
import functions.device_stats
import num2words
import sys,os
import functions.check_user
from functions.Response import say,listen

def check():
    say("Starting Program")
    say("Initializing modules")
    say("Modules Intialized")
    say("Performing System Checks")
    say("Sytem Checks Done")
    say("Starting happy protocol")
    
check()
```

Any Idea? what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is missing a lot of information. This is not a problem because I have been where you are. You are missing some lines of code. Instead of importing things like the say function or response, here is a working and simpler alternative.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr


engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def say(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def check():
    say("Starting Program")
    say("Initializing modules")
    say("Modules Intialized")
    say("Performing System Checks")
    say("Sytem Checks Done")
    say("Starting happy protocol")

check()
```

And you can essentially add commands for your virtual assistant later on...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did figure it out, Actually in my code, after calling the listener I supplied it with an empty string such as  var=" ", which called my listen at the starting. I removed that and it solved the problem